# Calculating for n = 1 $a^n -b^n = (a-b)(a^{n-1} + b a^{n-2} + b^2 a^{n-3} + ... + b^{n-2}a + b^{n-1})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Calculating for n = 1 $$a^n -b^n = (a-b)(a^{n-1} + b a^{n-2} + b^2 a^{n-3} + ... + b^{n-2}a + b^{n-1})$$
For n = 1,
we get,
$$a^1 -b^1 = (a-b)(a^{1-1}  + b^{1-1})$$
$$a^1 -b^1 = (a-b)(a^{0}  + b^{0})$$
$$a^1 -b^1 = (a-b)(1  + 1)$$

> $$a -b = 2 \cdot (a-b)$$

My question is, what wrong I did do to get this absurd result $$a -b = 2 \cdot (a-b)$$

P.S. I understood my stupid mistake. Thank you so much community for explaining.

Comment: The multiplicand $a^{n-1} + b a^{n-2} + b^2 a^{n-3} + ... + b^{n-2}a + b^{n-1}$ contains $n$ terms. When $n = 1$, the $a^{n-1}$ term (or, perhaps more revealingly, the $a^{n-1} b^0$ term) is actually *the same* as the $b^{n-1}$ (or $a^0b^{n-1}$) term.

Comment: @TheoBendit that's why we are getting 2 because they are the same.

Comment: @TheoBendit can you please explain it further? I didn't get it by you saying, "They are actually the same". If they are the same then what do we do with them?

Comment: They appear only once as a single entity and not as two separate entities to be added.   "*What do we do with them*" you mean what do we do with *it*, and the answer is nothing.  I.e. this expands as $a^1-b^1 = (a-b)(a^0b^0) = (a-b)(1) = (a-b)$

Comment: There is no "*other.*"  With a list with a single item in it, we could still refer to the "first" element in the list as well as the "last" element in the list but both are referring to the same thing.  If I want to write out an entire list, we could describe "write the first element, and then each subsequent element until writing the last" but with a one-element list we only need to write the singular element that appears noting that the "first" and the "last" are the same and writing of these is accomplished simultaneously and not as separate actions.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think I am asking it on the wrong website. I am getting more confused because I see a plus sign before  $b^{n-1}$

Comment: @TankFishToad Despite the downvotes (which I don't know how to account for; this seems to me a reasonably high-quality question to me), I do think this is a good site for this question. If you're not understanding things, let us know, and be patient. :-)

Comment: The $a^{n-1}+ba^{n-2}+\dots+b^{n-2}a+b^{n-1}$ expression is shorthand for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a^{n-k}b^{k-1}$.  The quantity of terms in the expansion of the sum is going to be $n$, regardless how many *example* terms appear in the ellipses form of the expression.  This is just like how "The sum of the first $n$ positive integers" might be written $1+2+3+\dots+n$ despite the fact that we could be talking about just the sum of the first two integers $1+2$ and that the term $3$ does not appear as one of the summands in that case despite appearing as an example term in $1+2+3+\dots+n$

Comment: @JMoravitz: That qualifies as an *answer,* don't you think?

Comment: @TankFishToad Also, think about the sum $1 + 2 + \ldots + n$. What would this be if $n = 2$? What would it be when $n = 1$? There is a $+$ before the final $n$, but it isn't meant to convey that there's at least two terms, just that you keep summing natural numbers until you get to $n$. As JMorvatiz points out, if $n = 1$, you'd start at $1$, get to $1$ (which is $n$), and stop with just the single summand.

Comment: @JMoravitz I understood my mistake. I am stupid to consider the last term as part of the first term. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @JMoravitz Plz put your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $a^{n-1} + b a^{n-2} + b^2 a^{n-3} + \ldots + b^{n-2}a + b^{n-1}$ sum contains precisely $n$ summands. Consider, for example:
\begin{align*}
a^2 - b^2 &= (a - b)(\underbrace{a^1b^0 + a^0b^1}_{\text{$2$ terms}}) \\
a^3 - b^3 &= (a - b)(\underbrace{a^2b^0 + a^1b^1 + a^0b^2}_{\text{$3$ terms}}) \\
a^4 - b^4 &= (a - b)(\underbrace{a^3b^0 + a^2b^1 + a^1b^2 + a^0b^3}_{\text{$4$ terms}})
\end{align*}
etc. In the $n = 1$ case, following this pattern, we should expect a single term:
$$a - b = (a - b)(a^0b^0).$$
This one term is simultaneously both the $a^{n-1}b^0$ term and the $a^0b^{n-1}$ term!

By adding $1$ twice to get $2$, you're actually erroneously repeating the one term in the sum. Note how consecutive terms in the sum will remove a power from $a$, but give a power to $b$ (so that the sum of the powers is always $n-1$)? If you add $a^0 + b^0 = a^0b^0 + a^0 b^0$, then you are breaking this pattern!

I hope that's more clear. Let me know if it isn't.